# Player walking through terrain bug

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I have this glitch/bug that I can walk through terrain with my player. I have tried so many things to fix it, but it seems like i need a hand. It seems like the problem appear when there is a hill or the terrain raise a little bit.

Normal view:
[image]

The bug:
[image]

Terrain options:

[image]

Player options:

[image]

Comment: Your player's `Rigid-body` has freeze position on the Y. Uncheck the box and test.

Comment: @Hristo Ops! Now my player stays at the height position?? When I walk upon a terrain, he won't go down to the ground again...

Comment: Increase the `Mass`, change your `Drag` as well

Comment: You know the standard values for that? Right now both is Infinity?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/Inspector-Rigidbody.png Also change the mass depending on your situation, experiment

Comment: @Please let me know if that worked out and I will provide an appropriate answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Thats becouse terrain renderer and terrain collider have different shapes.(so you are walking throught renderer, but not throught collider) Try to bake physics(cause physics rebaking) one more time before enter play mode.(thats should apply new shape for static terrain collider)